# conditionally calling a module using case statement

Tags: verilog

I want to implement module adder when `sel=0`, and module subtractor when `sel=1`. I learnt that generate can be used to call module within another module conditionally.

```
3.         module checker(o,a,b,sel);
4.         output reg o;
5.         input a,b,sel;
6.         always@(*)
7.         begin
8.         generate
9.         case (sel)                               
10.        1'b0 : adder a1(.sum(o),.a(a),.b(b));
11.        1'b1 : subtractor s1(.diff(o),.a(a),b(b));
12.        endcase
13.        endgenerate
14.        end
15.        endmodule

        //errors shown are:

    D:/FILES/verilog files/Neha/checker.v" Line 8: Syntax error near "generate".
    D:/FILES/verilog files/Neha/checker.v" Line 11: Port connections cannot be mixed ordered and named.
    D:/FILES/verilog files/Neha/checker.v" Line 13: Syntax error near "endgenerate".
    D:/FILES/verilog files/Neha/checker.v" Line 10: Instantiation is not allowed in sequential area except checker instantiation.
    D:/FILES/verilog files/Neha/checker.v" Line 11: Instantiation is not allowed in sequential area except checker instantiation
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're designing hardware here, not writing software. A Verilog `module` is a lump of hardware. You cannot "call" a Verilog `module` any more than you can "call" a chip on a PCB.

Your `adder` and `subtractor` modules are lumps of hardware. You cannot "call" them. What you need is some hardware - probably a multiplexer - to select the two outputs and drive the `o` output:

```
module checker(o,a,b,sel);
  output /* is this really 1 bit wide?   */ o;
  input  /* are these really 1 bit wide? */ a,b;
  input sel;

  wire   /* are these really 1 bit wide? */ sum, diff;;

  adder      a1(.sum(sum),   .a(a), .b(b));
  subtractor s1(.diff(diff), .a(a), .b(b));

  assign o = sel ? diff : sum;

endmodule
```

By the way - surely your inputs and outputs are more than 1 bit wide?

Comment: it was just an example, I need inputs and outputs both 32 bits wide. and need to do floating point addition or multiplication based on case statement(i.e. conditionally like when sel==0, F.P addition is performed and when sel==1 F.P multiplication is performed)!

Comment: hope u understood what I'm asking!

Comment: @Neha Is this `sel` _static_ or _dynamic_? If it were static then you can use a `generate` statement as you attempted to do. But it looks like `sel` is dynamic, because it is an input to `checker`. In which case, as @rahulcodesinverilog has said, you cannot use a `generate` statement; instead you _have_ to _instantiate_ (not "call") both modules and use a multiplexer to switch between their outputs (as I have done).  I'm not quite sure why it is necessary to use a `case` statement, but if you must use a `case` statememt then replace my `assign` with an `always` block containing one.

Comment: "Instantiation is not allowed in sequential area except checker instantiation".      what does this error means? why does this error occurs!

Comment: @Neha It sounds like you are trying to repeat the error you made in your original post. Generally, **you cannot instantiate a module inside procedural code**. To explain the actual detail of the error message: in SystemVerilog, `checker` is a reserved word; a `checker` is a special kind of module, which can actually be instantiated in procedural code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do like this. Since `generate` block is evauated before simulation, the `case` in `generate` needs a parameter or macro.

You can give `sel` as input to both modules and  do operations accordingly.

Here is how your module can look like:

```
module add_sub(input a,b,sel,output wire [1:0] s);

assign s = (sel) ? (a + b) : (a - b);

endmodule
```

Depending on `sel`, the operation must be performed.

The top module simply instantiates `add_sub` module.

```
module checker(o,a,b,sel);

add_sub a1(.a(a), .b(b), .sel(sel), .s(o));

endmodule
```

Comment: This was just an example I used to learn to call a module conditionally. actually I am working on floating point arithmetic which requires 32 bits inputs and outputs which can do floating point addition and multiplication conditionally!

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate the hardware on the fly while powered up. Hence, the logic has to be there.

If you would like to save on gates, you can use single adder instead of one adder and one subtractor. Pass value of b or -b(2's compliment) value to it based on select. In this way, you can save on subtraction logic.
Please use below as an example and correctly code.

```
assign b_final = sel ? b : -b;
assign s = a+ b_final;
```